# How do I process a video frame by frame in Android?

Tags: android, video-processing

I need to process a video frame by frame in Android. What I need is something that outputs a `Bitmap` (or copies everything to a memory buffer) At first I tried with `MediaMetadataRetriever` using the method `getFrameAtTime`, but I noticed that even if I am very careful with the timing, it skips frames. Is there a more reliable one?

Comment: Did you try mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(timeUs, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST)?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it skips entire sequences of frames